# Issues Converting the following SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Ok so I have been trying to figure out how to embed multiple select's
in a LINQ query and have been failing being that I don't use LINQ all that often.

I have come up with a fairly straight forward simple SQL statement I am trying to convert and I would appreciate it if anyone can help convert this to LINQ and explain the logic there.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE TABLE_B_REF IN
(SELECT TABLE_B_REF FROM TABLE_B
WHERE TABLE_B.TABLE_C_REF IN 
(SELECT TABLE_C_REF FROM TABLE_C WHERE C_NUMBER = '10001'))
```

I have googled around but what I am getting is too complex to follow for multiple embedded
queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [SQL join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) seems much simpler here. Assuming you've set up [navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) correctly, that would look a bit like this:

```
from a in db.TableA
where a.TableB.TableC.C_Number == "10001"
select a;
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
db.TableA.Where(a => a.TableB.TableC.C_Number == "10001")
```

The corresponding SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TABLE_A a
JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.TABLE_B_REF = b.TABLE_B_REF
JOIN TABLE_C c ON b.TABLE_C_REF = c.TABLE_C_REF
WHERE c.C_NUMBER = '10001'
```